# Running two threads at once, and subsequently communicating between them

Tags: java, multithreading, flow-control

I am trying to implement a stop and wait ARQ using a sender and receiver communicating on the same machine. My problem is making the two threads run simultaneously and, after that, communicating between the two threads (maybe using `Thread.notify()`). At the moment the code i have works when i run two separate main methods inside the 2 classes, without the flow control protocol implemented. However when I try and run the code from a separate main method, I can only run the Receiver thread or the Sender thread first, either of which causes the code to wait indefinitely. Im new to threading in general so any help is greatly appreciated!

Sender class:

```
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import tcdIO.*;

/**
 *
 * Sending side of a communication channel.
 *
 * The start method splits an image into a number of packets and sends them to a given receiver.
 * The main method acts as test for the class by filling the destination host and port number and the source port number.
 *
 */
public class Sender implements Runnable{
    static final int DEFAULT_SRC_PORT = 50000;
    static final int DEFAULT_DST_PORT = 50001;
    static final String DEFAULT_DST_HOST = "localhost";

    static final String FILENAME = "input.jpg";

    static final int MTU = 1500;

    static Terminal terminal;

    DatagramSocket socket;
    InetSocketAddress dstAddress;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     */
    Sender() {
        this(DEFAULT_DST_HOST, DEFAULT_DST_PORT, DEFAULT_SRC_PORT);
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     *   
     * Attempts to create socket at given port and create an InetSocketAddress for the destinations
     */
    Sender(String dstHost, int dstPort, int srcPort) {
        try {
            dstAddress= new InetSocketAddress(dstHost, dstPort);
            socket= new DatagramSocket(srcPort);
        }
        catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    synchronized void sleep() {
        try {this.wait(100);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }


    /**
     * Sender Method
     * 
     * Transmits a given image as a collection of packets; the first packet contains the size of the image as string.
     */
    public void run() {
        byte[] data= null;
        DatagramPacket packet= null;

        File file= null;
        FileInputStream fin= null;
        byte[] buffer= null;
        int size;
        int counter;

        try {   
            file= new File(FILENAME);               // Reserve buffer for length of file and read file
            buffer= new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fin= new FileInputStream(file);
            size= fin.read(buffer);
            if (size==-1) throw new Exception("Problem with File Access");
            terminal.println("File size: " + buffer.length + ", read: " + size);

            data= (Integer.toString(size)).getBytes();  // 1st packet contains the length only
            packet= new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, dstAddress);
            terminal.println("Please press any key");
            terminal.readChar();
            socket.send(packet);            

            counter= 0;
            do {
                data= new byte[(counter+MTU<size) ? MTU : size-counter];  // The length of the packet is either MTU or a remainder
                java.lang.System.arraycopy(buffer, counter, data, 0, data.length);
                terminal.println("Counter: " + counter + " - Payload size: " + data.length);

                packet= new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, dstAddress);
                socket.send(packet);
                this.sleep();   
                counter+= data.length;
            } while (counter<size);

        terminal.println("Send complete");
    }
    catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sender s;
    try {           
        String dstHost;
        int dstPort;
        int srcPort;

        //dstHost= args[0];
        //dstPort= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        //srcPort= Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        dstHost= DEFAULT_DST_HOST;
        dstPort= DEFAULT_DST_PORT;
        srcPort= DEFAULT_SRC_PORT;

        terminal= new Terminal("Sender");

        s= new Sender(dstHost, dstPort, srcPort);
        s.run();

        terminal.println("Program completed");
    } catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Receiver Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;

import tcdIO.*;

/**
 * Receiving side of a communication channel.
 *
 * The class provides the basic functionality to receive a datagram from a sender.
 * The main method acts as test for the class by filling the port number at which to receive the datagram.
 */
public class Receiver implements Runnable{
    static final String FILENAME = "output.jpg";
    static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 50001;
    static final int MTU = 1500;
    static Terminal terminal;

    DatagramSocket socket;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     */
    Receiver() {
        this(DEFAULT_PORT);
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     *   
     * Attempts to create socket at given port
     */
    Receiver(int port) {
        try {
            socket= new DatagramSocket(port);
        }
        catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Receiver Method
     * 
     * Attempts to receive a number of packets that contain an image; the first packet contains the size of the image
     */
    public void run() {
        byte[] data;
        byte[] buffer;
        DatagramPacket packet;
        int counter;
        int size;

        File file;
        FileOutputStream fout;

        try {
            data= new byte[MTU];  // receive first packet with size of image as payload
            packet= new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            terminal.println("Waiting for incoming packets");
            socket.receive(packet);         

            data= packet.getData();   // reserve buffer to receive image
            size= (Integer.valueOf(new String(data, 0, packet.getLength()))).intValue();
            terminal.println("Filesize:" + size);
            buffer= new byte[size];

            counter= 0;         
            while(counter<size) {  // receive packet and store payload in array
                data= new byte[MTU];
                packet= new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                terminal.println("Received packet - Port: " + packet.getPort() + " - Counter: " + counter + " - Payload: "+packet.getLength()); 

                System.arraycopy(data, 0, buffer, counter, packet.getLength());
                counter+= packet.getLength();
            }

            file= new File(FILENAME);               // Create file and write buffer into file
            fout= new FileOutputStream(file);
            fout.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
        }
        catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }


    /**
     * Test method
     * 
     * Creates an instance of the class Receiver
     * 
     * @param args arg[0] Port number to receive information on
     * /
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Receiver r;

        try {
            terminal= new Terminal("Receiver");
            int port;

            //port= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            port= DEFAULT_PORT;
            r= new Receiver(port);  
            r.run();

            terminal.println("Program completed");
        } catch(java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    */
}
```

And the main, which just instantiates both and runs them:

```
import tcdIO.Terminal;


public class FlowControlMain {

    /**
     * 
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sender s;
        Receiver r;
        try{
            String dstHost= "localhost";
            int dstPort= 50001;
            int srcPort= 50000;

            Sender.terminal= new Terminal("Sender");
            Receiver.terminal = new Terminal("Receiver");

            s= new Sender(dstHost, dstPort, srcPort);
            r = new Receiver(dstPort);
            s.run();
            r.run();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


}
```

Apologies for the massive amount of code, just trying to give a complete picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using threads, you're executing the `run()` method in your main thread.

The correct way to start a `Runnable` in its own `Thread` is either

```
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
t.start();
```

or to use an `ExecutorService`, which is a bit higher level and allows things such as thread pooling.

Comment: Many thanks! In terms of communication between them would notify() work?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by communication. The wait/notify mechanism allows you to control the threads, making one (or more threads) wait for the other to finish some task before proceeding.

Comment: thats exactly what i need to happen, i need the sender thread to wait for the receiver to confirm receipt of the packet before transmitting  the next one

Comment: Im assuming its something to do with the 'synchronized' statement, but im not really sure how to implement that

Comment: Well, wait() makes the thread wait for a notify() from another thread, and yes synchronized is involved (wait and notify need to be called from inside a synchronized context). There's plenty of tutorials about it.